# QTextEdit update single QTextCharFormat

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

I'm trying to update the QTextCharFormat for a single character. But it is not applied:

```
QTextCursor cursor(document());
cursor.setPosition(4);
QTextCharFormat format;
format.setFontPointSize(sizeString.toInt());
cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
qDebug() << "SET POS " << cursor.position() << " TO " << sizeString.toInt();

QTextCursor cursor2(document());
cursor.setPosition(4);
QTextCharFormat charformat = cursor2.charFormat();
QFont font = charformat.font();
qDebug() << " LOADED FONTSIZE: " << font.pointSize();
```

Output:

```
SET POS  4  TO  16
 LOADED FONTSIZE:  36
```

Any idea what's missing?

Comment: I am not that familiar with the cursors but don't you have to make a selection (moveCursor and keep the anchor so you have some text selected)?

Comment: i just tried this.. i think i'm missing the right function to apply the changed QTextCharFormat

Comment: have you checked the example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-cursor.html at "Manipulating Rich Text"

Comment: @Hayt YOU WHERE RIGHT! The selection was missing, it just did not work, because i did not move cursor2 is my test - please post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a change to apply you have to select a part of text (like in a real editor). 
You only set the cursor to a position without actually selecting things.

If you want to select text you have to move the cursor to another position with keeping the selection start.

```
cursor.setPosition(4);
cursor.setPosition(5, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
```

This sets the cursor to position 4. Then moves the cursor to position 5 but keeping the selection anchor. Which results in everything between position 4 and 5 being selected.

Now your changes will be applied to the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Example of the correct usage:

Get the cursor of your QTextEdit

```
QTextEdit *editor = new QTextEdit();
QTextCursor cursor(editor->textCursor());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
```

Set up your different QTextCharFormat

```
QTextCharFormat plainFormat(cursor.charFormat());

QTextCharFormat headingFormat = plainFormat;
headingFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
headingFormat.setFontPointSize(16);

QTextCharFormat emphasisFormat = plainFormat;
emphasisFormat.setFontItalic(true);
```

Now insert text in the text edit using different formats

```
cursor.insertText(tr("Character formats"),
                  headingFormat);

cursor.insertBlock(); // Single character
cursor.insertText(tr("a"), emphasisFormat);
cursor.insertText(tr("b"), headingFormat);
cursor.insertBlock();


cursor.insertText(tr("Text can be displayed in a variety of "
                              "different character formats. "), plainFormat);
cursor.insertText(tr("We can emphasize text by "));
cursor.insertText(tr("making it italic"), emphasisFormat);
```

If you want to change the style of a editable widget in real time of just render a text with different styles, you have an example in this url: [Syntax Highlighter Example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html)

Comment: do you have an example how to change the QTextCharFormat of already existing text?

Comment: No, sorry. Check the attached link.